# What is this function gonna return to these inputs?

Tags: javascript

I´ve been ask to find out, what:

```
function foo(input) {

var output = "intet match!";
if (input.length <= 5) {
    output = input;
} else if (input.length < 12) {
    output = input + "#" + input;
} else if (input == 'anders') {
    output = "[" + input + "]";
}
return output;
```

would return, if following input were entered:

- Peter Pedal
- Rub
- Gummi Tarzan
- Anders

Comment: Would really like some help, please. :)

Comment: OMG. New level of laziness.

Comment: Try it out in browser console

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MariaVissingBachara Here we help you with the problems you face during programming/coding ... If you have any problem related to the function/result or question related to it.. We would be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try just calling the function and passing the arguments you want to check, so you can see the output for yourself. You can, for example, <kbd>Copy + Paste</kbd> the whole code from below into your browser's developer console and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. For most browsers, dev tools open with <kbd>CtrL + Shift + c</kbd>.

```js
function foo(input) {

  var output = "intet match!";

  if (input.length <= 5) {
      output = input;
  } else if (input.length < 12) {
      output = input + "#" + input;
  } else if (input == 'anders') {
      output = "[" + input + "]";
  }

  return output;

}

console.log("Output for foo Peter Pedal input :",  foo('Peter Pedal'));
console.log("Output for foo Rub input         :",  foo('Rub'));
console.log("Output for foo Gummi Tarzan input:",  foo('Gummi Tarzan'));
console.log("Output for foo Anders input      :",  foo('Anders'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it's simple, but just posted a snippet here. `Click` the Run code snippet to check the results

```js
function foo(input) {

var output = "intet match!";
if (input.length <= 5) {
    output = input;
} else if (input.length < 12) {
    output = input + "#" + input;
} else if (input == 'anders') {
    output = "[" + input + "]";
}
return output;
}

['Peter Pedal','Rub','Gummi Tarzan','Anders'].forEach(val => { console.log(`For ${val}: ${foo(val)}`); });
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Input: Peter Pedal
   This will match the else if part (input.length < 12) and the output variable 
   will have a new value **Peter Pedal#Peter Pedal**

2) Input: Rub
   This is a straightforward scenario of if clause getting executed and returning 
   **Rub** as output.

3) Input: Gummi Tarzan
   None of the condition would match in this case and thus output will have **intet match!** returning as it is.

4) Input: Anders
   Here, the if clause would get executed and output will have **Anders#Anders**